# Moving Average Crossover Inflection Points

Tags: quantitative-finance

So, I am analyzing performance of stocks using Python. I have calculated moving averages and have all other data in one data frame. I am trying to find the points where the moving averages cross over the price and the duration of the crossover.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Read [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Let's start with showing first, what have you tried so far and how it worked, ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sample which compare the cross and if there is a cross than it places "1" in the signal. you should play with it to fit your needs.

```
short_window = 10
long_window = 50

df['signal'] = 0.0

roll_d10 = df.rolling(window=short_window).mean()
roll_d50 = df.rolling(window=long_window).mean()

df['short_mavg'] = roll_d10
df['long_mavg'] = roll_d50
df['signal'][short_window:] = np.where(df['short_mavg'][short_window:]
                                            > signals['long_mavg'][short_window:], 1.0, 0.0)
```

also, you should check [this](https://www.quantinsti.com/blog/strategy-using-trend-following-indicators-macd-st-adx/) for another example